# A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake / Login process

Tags: sql-server, authentication, entity-framework-4

I develop an SMS Server that receive SMS, Analysis them and reply to messages. This application developed with entity framework 4.0 and SQLServer 2008.

When I receive SMS I run new thread for that message and analysis and response to message. Each thread has its own new instance of object context and all threads call same stored procedure in SQL Server.

But when large number of SMS arrived to server and number of thread increase, I get one of these 2 error each time:

> The underlying provider failed on
>   Open. A connection was successfully
>   established with the server, but then
>   an error occurred during the pre-login
>   handshake. (Provider: TCP Provider,
>   error: 0 - The specified network name
>   is no longer available.)

OR

> The underlying provider failed on
>   Open. A connection was successfully
>   established with the server, but then
>   an error occurred during the login
>   process. (Provider: TCP Provider,
>   error: 0 - The specified network name
>   is no longer available.)

I increase  Max Pool Size and Connect Timeout to 400 and 150.
Can anyone help me??
Thanx

Comment: Are you solve this , i have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You might try increasing the timeout setting in SQL Server. The default is 10 minutes.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189040(v=sql.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189040%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Might be because some connections still get available. Try to do this :
`sp_configure 'user connections', 0
go
reconfigure with override`

Also check your server properties, in `Connections section`, that your parameter : `Maximum number of concurrent connections` is set to 0 (unlimited).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, 98% sure, because I recently had the same experience, it is a network issue from the server provider.

for instance: if you are rent the server from Ionos, by default all remote connections are blocked, even though you disable the firewall in the server. you still won't be able to connect remotely. You can, however, do your work on the server without any problem.

To connect remotely, you have to contact the Server provider. They will explain how to enable firewall ports from your control panel.

I contacted my server provider as I almost get frustrated.
here was their response.

[click to see the snapshot of their response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MUWN.png)

And, whola!! every permitted client can connect remotely to the server.

I wish you success.